# Unrecognized selector sent to instance - UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, objective-c++

I am in `tableviewcontroller.m` and have this message:

`-{UIViewController setDetailModal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8aaf310.`

How can I solve this to move on to my detailview controller?

Answer (score 2):

In your xib or storyboard file, set the class of your detail view controller to the name of your detail view controller subclass.  Currently, the runtime thinks it's a plain UIViewController.

Comment: It's not just that the runtime *thinks* it's a plain UIViewController -- it *is* a plain UIViewController.  Wherever `setDetailModal:` is being invoked the wrong object is being used.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the second target I had did not have the checkbox for the .m file selected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the name of the class in my file to match the name of the file itself.